# svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository (How can i enable the repository)

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, svn

while i'm promoting the code from local system to SVN Repository through using Jenkins with help of  batch file i'm getting the below error. but when i tried the same file from manual it's working fine, when i run the Jenkins job getting the issue, 
Please help anyone

[image: strong text]

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the error:

`Access to '/svn/.../branches/dist' forbidden.`

It means that the user account used in your build script to authenticate to the SVN server does not have Read permission to this repository URL. Contact your colleagues or admin for help.